# Ads are not working properly on android app

Tags: android, admob, signed-apk

I created a android app, and I implemented everything by referring the official admob tutorial. I signed my apk, but when I installed it the ads are not showing. Is it necessary to uplaod app on playstore to see the ads?

Comment: Check if you're using your own admob I'd and ad id

Comment: That's my own admob I'd

Comment: As far as I know ads are shown in your application only when you reach the required no. Of downloads for your application. If your app is not crashing or showing any errors in the logcat related to the ads then it's because of the limit your app need to reach.  https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9469204?hl=en#:~:text=Sample%20apps%20show%20how%20to,Google%20Mobile%20Ads%20SDK%20correctly.&text=Test%20your%20implementation%20code%20to,%2C%20ads%20won't%20show.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not necessary. Try to find any admob/ads related errors/warnings/info in the logcat during the startup of the app

Comment: When I am using the sample I'd, the sample ad is being shown, I am unable to test it with my own I'd becz of Google's policy and that's why I created a signed copy and then installed it on an android phone, when I ran the app the ads are not showing not even the sample ads

Comment: I repeat. Try to find any admob/ads related errors/warnings/info in the logcat during the startup of the app with the signed apk